# Seeking routing libraries in R?

Tags: r, routing, software-recommendations, sp

I'm trying find libraries for R that would find the shortest route between two locations, given a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` representing the road network. All I could find was [stplanr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=stplanr), which delegates the routing to external services such as CycleStreets.net (which does not cover the area I'm interested in) or GraphHopper (which is expensive).

What am I missing? Are there open routing packages for R available on GitHub or CRAN?

(My preference on an R package is due to the routing solution being a part of a larger application, and a native lib would be easier to integrate.)

Comment: Hmm, may be that I've been looking in the wrong direction. It appears you can convert `SpatialLinesDataFrame`s to [igraph](http://igraph.org/r/) objects using, for example, the [shp2graph](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shp2graph) library. [igraph](http://igraph.org/r/) objects, in turn, can easily be queried for shortest paths between edges (see `igraph::get.shortest.paths()`). See example (without [shp2graph](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shp2graph)) here: http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/6767_68df63f170214ba2ae39bbbe6560e5ef.html.

Comment: The `SpatialLinesDataFrame` -> `igraph` -> Dijkstra method is very slow with the road network of one medium-sized city, though, and even seems to occasionally crash R. Another package, [gdistance](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdistance/vignettes/gdistance1.pdf) seems to be doing the right thing, but with rasters rather than road networks. It could perhaps be used, writing a `Transition` wrapper for the `SpatialLinesDataFrame` road network.

Comment: Did you try the `TSP` ( Traveling Salesperson Problem)?

Answer (score 3):

Together with the `stplanr` authors I started some work on this in https://github.com/edzer/spnetwork , but I'm not so sure this is helpful - we stopped developing it at some stage, mostly because stplanr went for routing services. You may also want to look at CRAN package osmar, but I doubt that sees active development.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use street network data from OpenStreetMap , these are some of the best `R` packages for routing analysis:

- [r5r](https://ipeagit.github.io/r5r/): Rapid Realistic Routing with R5 in R
- [dodgr](https://github.com/ATFutures/dodgr): Distances on Directed Graphs in R
- [opentripplanner](https://github.com/ropensci/opentripplanner): OpenTripPlanner for R
- [stplanr](https://github.com/ropensci/stplanr): sustainable transport planning with R